# How to properly formally argue the unboundedness of a sum of supremums

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, infinity, formal-proofs

Suppose I wanted to prove that for some positive constants $d$ and $e$
$$d\sup_{x\in \textbf{R}^{+}}x + e\sup_{y\in \textbf{R}^{+}}y = +\infty$$

How would I do this? Obviously this an intuitive example, however, it doesn't feel correct to simply say something like:

> Because both supremums equal infinity, multiplied by any positive coefficient is still infinity, and thus the sums are still infinity

Since saying it "equals" infinity is just notational shorthand to saying the supremum is unbounded above.

How do I properly argue about this formally?

Edit: For clarity, I'm not married to the specific example. I'm just concerned about how to generally argue about sums/products of unbounded supremums.

Comment: Take $d=e=1$ and note that LHS $\geq (1)(n)+(1)(n)$ fro all $n$.

Comment: Hmm. Okay. But this approach seems to only work for this exact given example. I was hoping for a more general technique rather than something specific.

Comment: Like, I chose the supremums because they were convenient but what if I had some other arbitrary unbounded supremum? It just doesn't sit well with me

Answer (score 1):

The precise answer to this question is that since $\sup x=\infty$, you cannot multiply it with a number and add it to yet something else, because **$\infty$ is not a number, and "$=\infty$" is just a shorthand for a longer sentence about some quantity being unbounded above**.

Now you *can* theoretically define some algebraic rules for $\infty$ and thus artificially make it a number, such as $k\cdot\infty=\infty$ when $k$ is a positive real number, $\infty +\infty = \infty$, etc. But then your question is void, the equality that you want to prove follows trivially from these rules that you decided to add.

Comment: Then how I go arguing about supremums? I'm not sure how I would invoke limits here